# How to turn off git notifyCommit web hook trigger for individual Jenkins jobs?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a couple of Jenkins jobs in a build pipeline. One of them is a performance test and takes a long time to run. I would like it to run only once per day, or at least during a permitted time window at night.

Currently the job gets triggered by:

- [BuildResultTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)

  - monitors previous job in pipeline (build phase)
  - status: SUCCESS or UNSTABLE
  - schedule: @midnight
- [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin): `notifyCommit` on push events, by a web hook in the GitLab server.

If it were only for the BuildResultTrigger, then it would be good enough for me. However the `notifyCommit` web hook triggers *every* job that uses the same git repository as defined in the URL. And I can't *not* use the git repository, because obviously. (unless there is a way?)

What I am looking for:

- Either a way to turn off the git `notifyCommit` web hook trigger for an individual job.
- Or a way to define a time window, like from 00:00 AM to 04:00 AM, which is the only time the job is allowed to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the [Clone Workspace SCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin).

This plugin makes it possible to archive the workspace from builds of one project and reuse them as the SCM source for another project.

- Job A builds the project
- At the end of a successful build, the Clone Workspace SCM plugin archives the build workspace
- Job B does not use Git SCM, so it won't get activated by the git `notifyCommit` web hook trigger.
- Job B uses Clone Workspace SCM to retrieve the last successful build of Job A.
- Job B runs performance tests once per day, scheduled around `@midnight`.

I was also using the [Shared Workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin), but I will not use that any more. Clone Workspace better fits my needs.