# Jenkins: Clone workspace plugin does not clone .git directory

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using the [Clone Workspace SCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) plugin in a build pipeline (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010270/766786)). It is configured to include `**/*`.

The plugin does not copy the `.git` directory or the `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files. I need the `.git` directory for one of the jobs in the pipeline and I cannot use the git SCM directly, because then the job would get triggered by push events and I don't want that. (see linked question)

So how do I tell the Clone Workspace SCM to include the `.git` directory?

I tried with `**/*,.git/` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question:

The Clone Workspace SCM apparently uses something called the "Ant default excludes". I found the answer in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351685/766786) that points to the [Apache Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes).

```
**/.git
**/.git/**
**/.gitattributes
**/.gitignore
```

are part of the default excludes.

*Fortunately* the Clone Workspace SCM plugin has a checkbox **Override Default Ant Excludes**. Enable that, problem solved!